# p5.js : Trouble with clicking buttons and objects

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am really new to p5.js, and I'm trying to find a solution to this for a few days with no luck.

I have a button and an ellipse. When the button is clicked a rectangle appears on the canvas and when the ellipse is clicked its color changes.The problem is that I can't have both at the same time and the reason is this part of the code:

`stroke(rgb);
 strokeWeight(2);`

If I have it on my code, when I click the button the rectangle appears, but when I click the ellipse nothing happens. If I leave it out of my code, I can change the ellipse's color, but when I click the button nothing happens.
I have no idea why these two lines of code make it impossible to interact with both the button and the shape, and I'd really like to find out. Am I missing something important?

My code is the following:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  bubble = new new_ellipse(500,300);
}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  
  button = createButton("clickme");
  button.position(100, 65);
  button.mousePressed(show_rect);
  
  bubble.display();

  stroke(rgb);
  strokeWeight(2);
}

function mousePressed(){
    bubble.clicked();
}

function new_ellipse(x,y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.col = color(255,100);

  this.display = function(){
      stroke(255);
      fill(this.col);
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, 100, 100);
  }
  
  this.clicked = function(){
    var d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
    if(d < 50){
       this.col = color(233,11,75);
    }
  }
}

function show_rect(){
  fill(255,24,23);
  rect(200,200,100,100);
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to call the `createButton()` function from the `draw()` function. That's going to create 60 different buttons per second.

Comment: One thing to fix may be that the variable `rgb` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Two related issues:

- Don't call `createButton` inside `draw`. `draw` is called about 60 times a second, so this spams buttons. `draw` is your animation loop. Use `setup` to set things up.
- Given that `draw()` runs 60 times a second, any calls to `show_rect` triggered by a button press will be almost instantly wiped clean by `background(51)` a split second later.

  One option is to introduce a boolean to keep track of whether the button has been pressed yet, then re-draw it every frame if it's supposed to be visible.

  Another approach is to drop the `draw()` function and re-paint only when state changes. This prevents `background(51)` from blasting everything and is efficient, but also isn't suitable if you have animations or a good deal of dynamism in your app.

Here's a sample of the first approach, using a boolean:

```js
var bubble, button;
var shouldShowRect = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  bubble = new Ellipse(500, 300);
  button = createButton("clickme");
  button.mousePressed(function () {
    // or set to true if you don't want to toggle
    shouldShowRect = !shouldShowRect;
  });
  button.position(100, 65);
}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  bubble.display();
  
  if (shouldShowRect) {
    showRect();
  }

  strokeWeight(2);
}

function mousePressed() {
  bubble.clicked();
}

function Ellipse(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.col = color(255, 100);

  this.display = function() {
    stroke(255);
    fill(this.col);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 100, 100);
  }

  this.clicked = function() {
    var d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, this.x, this.y);
    if (d < 50) {
      this.col = color(233, 11, 75);
    }
  }
}

function showRect() {
  fill(255, 24, 23);
  rect(200, 200, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```